# select data header join detail last doc_num header is promotion?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, named t_header and t_detail.

this data header

```
ID | doc_num | promotion
1     0001      0
2     0002      1
```

this data detail

```
ID | doc_num | item | price
1     0001      2      100
2     0001      3      170
3     0001      4      102
4     0001      5      105
5     0002      3      120
6     0002      4       99
7     0002      7      165
```

if promo = 1, then the price in detail would take detailed data promo price, for the table above if the item = 3 then will take the price = 120 because the item with doc_num 002 promo = 1, if no promo it will take prices docnum 001, 001 num doc standard prices, and group by item

output

```
ID | doc_num | item | price | promotion
1     0001      2      100    0
5     0002      3      120    1
6     0002      4      99     1
4     0001      5      105    0
7     0002      7      165    0
```

Comment: Your explanation is unclear, please edit your question to include expected output

Comment: I don't understand either. `item = 2` has `doc_num = 0001`, which is `promo = 0` and also has `doc_num = 0002`, which is `promo = 1`.

Comment: I've added the output I expected

Comment: when in the join suppose promo = 1 takes the promo price by item

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to select promo price if it's available otherwise you need normal price. So you should select columns using IF statement after LEFT JOIN. 
this query may help :

```
SELECT
if(td_prom.ID, td_prom.ID, td_norm.ID) as ID, 
th.doc_num,
if(td_prom.price, td_prom.price, td_norm.price) as price,
if(td_prom.item, td_prom.item, td_norm.item) as item,
th.promo
FROM
t_header th
LEFT JOIN t_detail as td_norm ON th.doc_num = td_norm.doc_num AND th.promo = 0
LEFT JOIN t_detail as td_prom ON th.doc_num = td_prom.doc_num AND th.promo = 1
GROUP BY item
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in you desired result, you don't want items to be shown twice. Next to this I assume you have an items table in your database. Then I came up with this query. 
First part is to extract items in promo.
Second part add only those items which are not in promo, but exclude items that have a promo on them.

```
SELECT d.id, d.doc_num, d.item, d.price, h.promo
FROM items AS i
  INNER JOIN detail AS d ON i.id = d.id
  INNER JOIN header AS h ON h.doc_num = d.doc_num AND h.promo = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT nopromo.*
FROM (SELECT d.id, d.doc_num, d.item, d.price, h.promo
      FROM items AS i
        INNER JOIN detail AS d ON i.id = d.id
        INNER JOIN header AS h ON h.doc_num = d.doc_num AND h.promo = 0) AS nopromo
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT d.id, d.doc_num, d.item, d.price, h.promo
     FROM item AS i
       INNER JOIN detail AS d ON i.id = d.id
       INNER JOIN header AS h ON h.doc_num = d.doc_num AND h.promo = 1) AS ipromo
  ON nopromo.item = ipromo.item
WHERE ipromo.id IS NULL
ORDER BY item
```

Result

```
+---+--------+-----+------+------+
|id |doc_num |item |price |promo |
+---+--------+-----+------+------+
|1  |0001    |2    |100   |0     |
|5  |0002    |3    |120   |1     |
|6  |0002    |4    |99    |1     |
|4  |0001    |5    |105   |0     |
|7  |0002    |7    |165   |1     |
+---+--------+-----+------+------+
```